# Is there anyway to get the current object in has_permission method while calling DetailView in Django CBV

Tags: django, permissions, django-views, django-permissions

I have a DetailView where I want to restrict the access to the payment based on the user project assignment related to this payment.
I have the following code working just fine. Just wondering if there is a cleaner way to retrieve self.object within the has_permission instead of getting the object using the PK directly.

```
class PaymentDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Payment
    template_name = "finance/payments/details.html"
    context_object_name = "payment"

    def has_permission(self):
        payment = Payment.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get("pk"))
        # Check permission here based on the current user project assignment
        if condition:
            return True
        return False
```

I understand that has_permission is part of PermissionRequiredMixin and not the DetailView and this might not be possible but I wonder if there is a better way to test this object-based permission.

Note: the logic is a bit complicated and might not be as easy as a simple query (in fact it is actually based on the user role, project assignment, the time of assignment compared to the payment date, payment type.....)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

follow the documentation on how to create custom permissions.

your custom permission should look like this:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission, SAFE_METHODS

class CustomPermission(BasePermission): 

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
      .......
```

within has_permission you can do this:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission, SAFE_METHODS

class CustomPermission(BasePermission): 

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        id = view.kwargs.get('pk', None)
```

This would return you the `id` that was passed in the url, you can then get the object